# Testing library: You called act(async () => ...) without await

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm writing some react unit tests and I keep getting this warning in my console but I'm not sure if I'm actually doing anything wrong.

```
it('correctly returns postcodes found', async () => {
        const { input, user, onPostcodeLookup } = setup();

        act(async () => {
            user.type(input, 'NG1 6DQ');

            await waitFor(() => {
                expect(onPostcodeLookup).toHaveBeenCalled();
                expect(onPostcodeLookup).toHaveBeenCalledWith([mockedData]);
            });
        });
    });
```

The warning I get is:

```
 Warning: You called act(async () => ...) without await. This could lead to unexpected testing behaviour, interleaving multiple act calls and mixing their scopes. You should - await act(async () => ...);
```

The test:

1. Finds the postcode input
2. Types a postcode (using the `user-event` library)
3. Waits for some async callbacks to be called

But I legitimately don't think there's any other way to write this test...

If I remove `act`, I get this error:

```
Warning: An update to PostcodeLookup inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
```

If instead I remove `async and await` from act I get:

```
 Warning: You seem to have overlapping act() calls, this is not supported. Be sure to await previous act() calls before making a new one.
```

If I just wrap my `user.type` in `act` I get:

```
 Warning: You seem to have overlapping act() calls, this is not supported. Be sure to await previous act() calls before making a new one
```

Is this a bug? I cannot figure out how I'm supposed to write this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `setup` is, but if it's a DOM representation this might work using `fireEvent` from RTL:

```
it('correctly returns postcodes found', async () => {
  const { input, user, onPostcodeLookup } = setup();

  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'NG1 6DQ' } });

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(onPostcodeLookup).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(onPostcodeLookup).toHaveBeenCalledWith([mockedData]);
  });
});
```